# How to extract all emails from a string?

Tags: php, html, regex, string, email

How to remove ?
I have html file with 300 000 lines
I want to remove all contens, all tags, everything, but keep emails.
example in the file:

```
ght="20"valign="top"bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><spanclass="style43style44">+995</strong>

<a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">mail@mail.com</a>

:fefw.gefew?chat">rewews</a>
```

in this file is 1000 email address.

Comment: It seems blivit to me ;)

Comment: this is not spam @Dagon

a have old site with only html pages. now i do with PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this example:

```
<?php

$content = 'ght="20"valign="top"bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><spanclass="style43style44">+995</strong>

<a href="mailto:mail@mail.com">mail@mail.com</a>
<a href="mailto:pol@hotmail.it">pol@hotmail.it</a>
john@doe.col-
:fefw.gefew?chat">rewews</a>';

$matches = array(); //create array
$pattern = "/[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})/i";

preg_match_all($pattern, $content, $matches); 

print_r(array_values(array_unique($matches[0])));

?>
```

Comment: @BeQaNikolashvili don't forget check as correct ;-)

Comment: @BeQaNikolashvili in the checkmark at the left of the answer and at the bottom of the votes, where is in this moment the number 1

Comment: need 15 reputation ((